# Switching between fullscreen and non-fullscreen causing view offset

Tags: android, kotlin

I have an app where certain views need to be fullscreen, and others need to not be fullscreen. In some cases i want the background to be displayed under the status bar so I use this when the view loads to make the activity fullscreen:

```
window.decorView.systemUiVisibility = View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_STABLE or View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_FULLSCREEN
window.statusBarColor = Color.TRANSPARENT
```

and then in the other views i have this to switch back to non-fullscreen and show a status bar with a solid color so i use this when those views load:

```
window.decorView.systemUiVisibility = View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_VISIBLE or View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_STABLE
window.statusBarColor = ContextCompat.getColor(context, R.color.colorPrimaryDark)
```

However when I switch between these views the whole view will be offset by the size of the statusBar, going from fullscreen to non-fullscreen the whole view is too low and goes below the nav bar, going the other way causes the whole view to be too high and leaving a bit of white space between the nav bar and the bottom of the view.

I've tried calling `invalidate()` after setting the flags to force it to redraw but it seems to do nothing. Is there another call i can make to fix the offset caused by changing the window flags?

EDIT:

To give some more info - I am not switching between activities, I am simply switching which view is being displayed in the activity. When my view is attached I make the call to change the decorView flags

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay so I found a way to achieve this, not sure if ideal but it works... Essentially I just leave the app always in fullscreen and manually add/remove padding from my content view to make it expand behind the status bar or not.

Here's the implementation:

First I set my window flags to the following:

```
window.decorView.systemUiVisibility = (View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_IMMERSIVE
        or View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_STABLE
        or View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_FULLSCREEN)
```

then in my parent view I have these calls:

```
val statusBarHeight: Int
    get() {
        var result = 0
        val resourceId = resources.getIdentifier("status_bar_height", "dimen", "android")
        if (resourceId > 0) {
            result = resources.getDimensionPixelSize(resourceId)
        }
        return result
     }

private var shouldShowBlueBar: Boolean = false

private fun hideSystemUI() {
    // registered main view is the content view and I'm, setting it it to have
    // no padding so it goes right to the top of the screen and shows under the
    // status bar
    registered_main_view.setPadding(0, 0, 0 ,0)
    window.statusBarColor = Color.TRANSPARENT
}

private fun showSystemUI() {
    // here I put padding that is the height of the status bar to keep the
    // main content view below the status bar
    registered_main_view.setPadding(0, statusBarHeight, 0 ,0)
    window.statusBarColor = ContextCompat.getColor(context, R.color.colorPrimaryDark)
}

override fun toggleHeaderBlue(showBar: Boolean) {
    shouldShowBlueBar = showBar
    if (shouldShowBlueBar) {
        showSystemUI()
    } else {
        hideSystemUI()
    }
}

override fun onWindowFocusChanged(hasFocus: Boolean) {
    super.onWindowFocusChanged(hasFocus)
    if (shouldShowBlueBar)
        showSystemUI()
    else
        hideSystemUI()
}
```

and I just call toggleHeaderBlue() when i need to switch between showing or not showing the status bar.